# Problems running Compass Watch on a Drupal install with Omega 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, drupal, rubygems

I've been debugging this install for awhile.  I know that the command compass watch works with other drupal installs, but this is my first time using it with the Omega theme.  I'm running into this error.

> > > C:\webdev\sites\all\themes\cee>compass watch
> > >        Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
> > >       ArgumentError on line ["500"] of C: different prefix: "C:/" and "C:\webdev/sites/all/themes/cee/sass"
> > >       Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

All the solutions I found online were for people who had their ruby install on another partition, but mine is on the same.  The problem appears to be the forward slashes instead of back slashes, but I'm not sure how to correct this.  I am running compass watch in the same directory as config.rb.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is running the command with --trace.
C:\webdev\sites\all\themes\cee>compass watc
h --trace

> > > Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
> > >       ArgumentError on line ["500"] of C: different prefix: "C:/" and "C:\webdev/sites/all/themes/cee/sass"
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-globbing-1.1.1/lib/sass/globbing/impo
> > >       rter.rb:60:in `mtime'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.9/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_check
> > >       er.rb:134:in`mtime'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.9/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_check
> > >       er.rb:163:in `block in dependency_updated?'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.9/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_check
> > >       er.rb:125:in`each'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.9/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_check
> > >       er.rb:125:in `any?'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.9/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_check
> > >       er.rb:125:in`dependencies_stale?'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.9/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_check
> > >       er.rb:166:in `block in dependency_updated?'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.9/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_check
> > >       er.rb:125:in`each'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.9/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_check
> > >       er.rb:125:in `any?'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.9/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_check
> > >       er.rb:125:in`dependencies_stale?'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.9/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_check
> > >       er.rb:166:in `block in dependency_updated?'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.9/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_check
> > >       er.rb:81:in`call'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.9/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_check
> > >       er.rb:81:in `stylesheet_modified_since?'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.9/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_check
> > >       er.rb:69:in`stylesheet_needs_update?'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.20/lib/compass/compile
> > >       r.rb:85:in `needs_update?'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.20/lib/compass/compile
> > >       r.rb:79:in`block in out_of_date?'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.20/lib/compass/compile
> > >       r.rb:78:in `each'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.20/lib/compass/compile
> > >       r.rb:78:in`out_of_date?'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.20/lib/compass/watcher
> > >       /compiler.rb:20:in `compile'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.20/lib/compass/command
> > >       s/watch_project.rb:47:in`perform'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.20/lib/compass/command
> > >       s/base.rb:18:in `execute'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.20/lib/compass/command
> > >       s/project_base.rb:19:in`execute'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.20/lib/compass/exec/su
> > >       b_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.20/lib/compass/exec/su
> > >       b_command_ui.rb:15:in`run!'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.20/bin/compass:30:in 
> > >       `block in <top (required)>'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.20/bin/compass:44:in`
> > >       call'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.alpha.20/bin/compass:44:in 
> > >       `<top (required)>'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/bin/compass:23:in`load'
> > >         C:/Ruby200/bin/compass:23:in `'

Additionally, I have also gotten this error several times during this debugging which I think is related.

> WDM::Error on line [73] of c: Can't get the absolute path for the passed directory: '' !
>   Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

Comment: While I never solved this exact problem, I managed to get it working after uninstalling everything and starting over.  I think part of the problem was that I was stuck in dependency hell.  Bundle helped me out, I ended up getting results with bundle exec compass compile, and edited my gem file with all of the missing dependencies.  That, with a bundle update, finally allowed compass to work properly by running bundle exec compass watch.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when updated Ruby to 2.0 version, the problem did not occur on older version of Ruby (1.9.3).

I deleted the new version of Ruby and got the older one back up (removed DevKit for 2.0 and installed DevKit for Ruby 1.9.3 too) and it all worked like a charm.